# What research is required over common knowledge words?

Tags: discussion

For [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/611774/do-terms-that-end-with-mate-need-to-be-clarified-where-people-say-mate), it was closed due to a lack of research. Seems like an arbitrary reason to close, especially when no comment is given for what type of research is lacking. I think most word usage is common knowledge, which includes all words I used. If the question was over something unknown, fair enough, but that wasn't the case here. Or do people just find any reason to close just because people don't like the question?

Comment: By the way, the first close vote was for lack of clarity (which is completely understandable considering the state the question was in at the time).

Comment: My reaction to that question on first reading it was that it was not serious (ie not in good faith, just messing around).  There might be a very good question hidden in there about ambiguity and polysemy , but it would be very generic and cross-language. As to the close reason, I don't know, the close reasons are not to be taken so literally. Wait... change 'Like...' to 'For example...' and end it with 'What is this phenomenon? How do people deal with it?'. I don't know if that'll get it reopened, but it'll move things away from 'Urban Dictionary' style.

Comment: Just because it's funny doesn't mean it's not in good faith. If someone orders Coffee-Mate, I wonder what the response is.

Comment: @user14094230 OK, I get that you are in good faith curious about 'what people do'. So to take it seriously, you simply disambiguate - eg "It's just 'Check'...mate, not 'Checkmate'" with pauses as needed, or you make an Abbot and Costello comedy routine out of it. 'How to say it' is usually more appropriate for [ELL.se].

Comment: That said, reopened!

Comment: I'm not asking how to say it, I'm asking if confusion ever occurs from how others say it. One it's not about pauses, it's about tonicity. So it seems people are pretending it's a basic question for learners who don't know what they're talking about. People don't pause before saying mate

Comment: You really need to stop deleting your account. In this case, since the question was downvoted with no positive answers, deleting your account caused the question to be deleted along with it.